# Method of a superclass is not being inherited by a subclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I'm following book about object oriented Python and I stumbled upon
code that quite doesn't make sense to me:

```
class Property:

    def __init__(self, square_feet='', beds='', baths='', **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.square_feet = square_feet
        self.num_bedrooms = beds
        self.num_baths = baths

    def display(self):
        print('PROPERTY DETAILS')
        print('----------------')
        print(f'square footage: {self.square_feet}')
        print(f'bedrooms: {self.num_bedrooms}')
        print(f'bathrooms: {self.baths}')
        print()

    def prompt_init():
        return dict(square_feet=input('Enter the square feet: '),
                beds=input('bedrooms: '), baths=input('baths: '))

    def get_valid_input(input_string, valid_options):
        input_string += ' ({}) '.format(', '.join(valid_options))
        response = input(input_string)
        while response.lower() not in valid_options:
            response = input(input_string)
        return response

    prompt_init = staticmethod(prompt_init)
```

then I have:

```
class House(Property):
    valid_garage = ('attached', 'detached', 'none')
    valid_fenced = ('yes', 'no')

    def __init__(self, num_stories='', garage='', fenced='', **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.garage = garage
        self.fenced = fenced
        self.num_stories = num_stories

    def display(self):
        super().display()
        print('HOUSE DETAILS')
        print(f'# of stories: {self.num_stories}')
        print(f'garage: {self.garage}')
        print(f'fenced yard: {self.fenced}')

    def prompt_init():
        parent_init = Property.prompt_init()
    --> fenced = get_valid_input('Is the yard fenced ? ',   House.valid_fenced)
        garage = get_valid_input('Is there a garage ? ', House.valid_garage)
        num_stories = input('How many stories ? ')

        parent_init.update({
            'fenced': fenced,
            'garage': garage,
            'num_stories': num_stories
        })
        return parent_init
        prompt_init = staticmethod(prompt_init)


class Rental:

    def __init__(self, furnished='', utilities='', rent='', **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.furnished = furnished
        self.utilities = utilities
        self.rent = rent

    def display(self):
        super().display()
        print('RENTAL DETAILS')
        print(f'rent: {self.rent}')
        print(f'estimated utilities: {self.utilities}')
        print(f'furnished: {self.furnished}')

    def prompt_init():
        return dict(
            rent=input('What is the monthly rent ? '), utilities=input('What are the estimated utilities ? '),
            furnished=input('Is the property furnished ? ', ('yes', 'no')))
    prompt_init = staticmethod(prompt_init)


class HouseRental(Rental, House):

    def prompt_init():
        init = House.prompt_init()
        init.update(Rental.prompt_init())
        return init
    prompt_init = staticmethod(prompt_ini
```

when I instantiate `HouseRental` class like this:

```
init = HouseRental.prompt_init()
```

I'm getting bunch of prompts as expected but I'm also getting error

> get_valid_input not defined

on the line I marked with `-->`, Which doesn't make sense to me because the method is defined in `Property` superclass and `House` class is a subclass of `Property` which inherits all methods `Property` have.

How come `House` class isn't recognizing the method?

Comment: please always use the generic [python] tag for all python related questions. Use the version specific tag at your discretion.

Comment: you know, you’ll get better results if you strip your example code to **just what’s relevant** before posting it.  also, doing so often allows you to figure it out yourself.  no offence intended.

Answer (score 1):

Pass `self` as the first argument to your `prompt_init` method in `House`, and call the inherited method with `self.get_valid_inputs(...)`.

In your `House` class:

```
def prompt_init(self):
    parent_init = Property.prompt_init()
    fenced = self.get_valid_input('Is the yard fenced ? ',   House.valid_fenced)
    garage = self.get_valid_input('Is there a garage ? ', House.valid_garage)
    num_stories = input('How many stories ? ')
    # ...
```

You also have to pass `self` as the first argument of the parent class's `get_valid_input` method. This is because Python automatically passes a reference to the calling object as the first argument to class methods, so if you do not account for that in your signature, you will get "too many arguments" errors.

In your `Property` class:

```
def get_valid_input(self, input_string, valid_options):
    input_string += ' ({}) '.format(', '.join(valid_options))
    response = input(input_string)
    # ...
```

Then `house = House().prompt_init()` ran without errors for me.

It looks like you might need to add `self` as an argument to all of your other `prompt_init` methods for your subclasses. Generally you should always pass `self` as the first argument to methods in a class.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was pulling the method out of the superclass and leaving it
in global scope like this:

```
def get_valid_input(input_string, valid_options):
    input_string += ' ({}) '.format(', '.join(valid_options))
    response = input(input_string)
    while response.lower() not in valid_options:
        response = input(input_string)
    return response


class Property:

    ...
    # other methods
    ...


class House(Property):

    ...
    # other methods
    ...

    def prompt_init():
        parent_init = Property.prompt_init()
        fenced = get_valid_input('Is the yard fenced ? ', House.valid_fenced)
        garage = get_valid_input('Is there a garage ? ', House.valid_garage)
        num_stories = input('How many stories ? ')

        parent_init.update({
            'fenced': fenced,
            'garage': garage,
            'num_stories': num_stories
        })
        return parent_init


class HouseRental(Rental, House):

    def prompt_init():
        init = House.prompt_init()
        init.update(Rental.prompt_init())
        return init
    prompt_init = staticmethod(prompt_init)
```

Comment: Did you try my answer? Maybe global scope will work for you, but I'd consider real carefully whether that makes sense for the use cases you are going for. Generally speaking, you'll probably want to be able to use methods inherited from the parent of a class, and my answer shows how you do that.

Comment: you really need to internalize what ‘self’ means in Python.  nothing wrong with having global standalone utility functions.  but when indented, class scope methods don’t have *self* that rings all kind of alarm bells.  been there myself, took me about 3-4 months, mostly because it seemed to work when i only had 1 instance of each class.  create 2 houserentals and check they are indeed isolated from each other.